# MySQL Query to count all records from multiple table

Tags: mysql, function, count

I want count the all records from all tables I tried this but this is not working.

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE FUNCTION countr(p_tablename varchar(10)) RETURN int(10) BEGIN DECLARE ra int; DECLARE table_count INT;
SET ra=
  (SELECT COUNT(*) INTO table_count
   FROM information_schema.tables
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dest_northwind'
     AND TABLE_NAME = p_tablename); RETURN ra; END$ DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do that...

```
SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();
```

Update - questioner wishes to only get the rows for a subset of tables so I've updated this to contain the sum of the individual tables or counts for those table son their own.

Sum of table rows...

```
SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
    AND TABLE_NAME IN ('Table2','Table1');
```

Table rows by table...

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,SUM(TABLE_ROWS) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
    AND TABLE_NAME IN ('Table2','Table1')
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: maybe if your question had indicated the exact error that would help.  I should also add this is 100% tested and working.

Comment: yes working but i want count of every table not sum of all rows

Comment: ok thank you for confirming it works, again I suggest editing your question - I see no difference (apart from my code is much more concise) with mine, but I'll add something to limit the tables.

Comment: Please go through this link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113427/how-to-fetch-data-from-two-db-and-insert-into-temp-table-using-sql

Comment: no thank you, I'm not going to keep answering a changing question.  I feel I've answered two questions here (after being told that it didn't work at first too).  You can either take my answer(s) or wait for others, or start another clearer question.  Best of luck :)